# php Form Checkbox INSERT data into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

**Hello Everyone** i'm new here,i want to create a form for my clients to choose the size of the product using checkboxes Small,Medium,Large and also the client info.Here is the code still can't figure out the problem,Please i need some help:i want to insert it into my table as an array (example: `size-->Medium` .. )

```
include("../admin/conn.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vm");

if(isset($_POST['passer'])){
    $nom=$_POST['nom'];
    $tel=$_POST['tel'];
    $adresse=$_POST['adresse'];
    $size = implode(",",$_POST['size']); //S M L
    $sql_size="INSERT INTO `salades` (id,size) VALUES('','".$size."')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql_size)){echo "Salade Size Added";}
    else{echo "Error";}
    $req_clt =mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `clt_vertmidi` (Id_clt,Nom_clt,      Tel_clt, Adresse_clt) VALUES ('','".$nom."', '".$tel."', '".$adresse."')");
    if(!$req_clt){die("Failed");
    }echo 'Client Added successfully!!!';
}
```

Comment: What happens with this code? Are you getting errors, no insertion, incorrect data written, etc? You also are open to SQL injections. You should parameterize the query, could also be your current issue..

Comment: `"still can't figure out the problem"` - Well, what indication do you have that there even *is* a problem?  We can't see your screen from here, you have to describe the problem to us.

Comment: Hi thanks for you quick answer yes i got the echo "Error"; that means the condition if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql_size)){echo "Salade Size Added";} don't execute.. right!!

Comment: @yassir.r: When there's an error, check what `mysqli_error($conn)` returns.  "Error" isn't a super useful message.

Comment: THankkss mr @David when i did it i solved the problem ..thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
$req_clt =mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `clt_vertmidi` (Id_clt,Nom_clt,      Tel_clt, Adresse_clt) VALUES ('','".$nom."', '".$tel."', '".$adresse."')");
```

Here you no need to add **Id_clt** field and make it auto increment in database.

Updated Query:

```
$req_clt =mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `clt_vertmidi` (Nom_clt,      Tel_clt, Adresse_clt) VALUES ('".$nom."', '".$tel."', '".$adresse."')");
```

Comment: Hi sir, yes i did it for the information insert there is no error it all about the checkboxes $sql_salsize="INSERT INTO `size` (id,size) VALUES ( '','".$size."')";

Comment: Good . Please like my answer :) if it helps you